# Claims on shortest path between two node in graph?

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, graph, graph-theory

if the shortest path between two vertex on weighted and directed graph `G` (maybe has negative edge), is shown by `D(u, v)`, the following claims is always false.

> with having negative edges, but didn't have any negative cycle, then
>   Sigma on D(u,v) (sum on all vertex pairs) cannot be negative.

```
Why this claims is False?
```

> what is `D(u,v)` where there's no path from u to v is not given in my
>   notes, but I think `D(u,v)=0` in this case.

Comment: Well if there is no path from `u` to `v` that's usually noted as `D(u,v) = infinity`, but that's definition dependent

Comment: if we use infinity this statement maybe true ? @amit okey ?

Comment: I have no idea, I can try to prove or find counter example, but it really depends on the answer for this question. If `D(u,v)=0` for no path between u-v, a DAG with only negative weight edges clearly answers the requirement, but this seems weird assumption to me.

Comment: so please consider two case via answer @amit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `D(u,v) = infinity` if there is no path from `u` to `v` (I really see no reason to assume otherwise, it is weird to assume `D(u,v)=0` in this case), the claim is true.

**Proof:**

First, assume there is a path for each pair `u,v` - otherwise sum of all pairs is infinity, and we are done.

For each pair of vertices `u,v`:

- If `D(u,v)>0` and `D(v,u)>0` this pair contribute positive number to the summation
- Otherwise, and without loss of generality, assume `D(u,v)<0`. Since there are no negative cycles, `D(u,v) + D(v,u) >= 0` and thus `D(v,u) >= -D(u,v)`. And as we see, `D(v,u) + D(u,v)`  contribute a non negative number for the summation.

Since the above is true for each pair `u,v` - there is no pair that can contribute a negative number, and the summation cannot be negative.

**QED**

Comment: another question arises, if we didnt have any negative cycle, then for each two vertex u,v, delta(u,v) is equal to -infinity ? this is false?

Comment: @AnjelaDark What's `delta(u,v)`? How is it defined?

Comment: D(u, v) means Delta @amit

Comment: @AnjelaDark I am not following the question - if we have no negative cycle, how could D(u,v)=-infinity?

Comment: sorrryyyy, please be kind with me :) if we have negative cycle, then for each two vertex u,v, delta(u,v) is equal to -infinity ? this is false?

Comment: @AnjelaDark This statement is false, look at the example: V={a,b,c,d} and assume a->b->a is a negative cycle, and the only one. It says nothing about c->d, it could be a positive value, no problem with that. If there is a negative cycle, if there is a path that goes through the cycle, then it's -infinity, but if there are mulriple Strongly Connected Components, it doesn't have to apply for other components.

Comment: thanks I Got it. my last question is can we say: if we didnt have any negative cycle, then delta(u,t) <= delta(u,v) + delta(v,t) ?

Comment: @AnjelaDark Yes, otherwise you can take the path u->v->t and have the same weight. However, Dijkstra's algorithm fails to see such connections and thus fails when there are negative weights (Bellman Ford works fine here)

Comment: Sorry for "if we have negative cycle, then for each two vertex u,v, delta(u,v) is equal to -infinity" I say That's not enough for making delta(u,v) equal to -infinity for any u, v; only for those where a path connecting them goes goes through any vertex of that cycle. In a strongly connected graph this would be true. my conclusion is right? @amit

Answer (score 1):

> with having negative edges, but didn't have any negative cycle, then Sigma on D(u,v) (sum on all vertex pairs) cannot be negative.

1. **D(u, v) = 0** for no arc `u -> v`

Consider the directed graph:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3
```

With each arc having cost `-1`: there is no negative cost cycle, but the sum over all pairs is negative. So the claim is false because we have found a counterexample.

2. **D(u, v) = infinity** for no arc `u -> v`

In this case, if we want to find a counterexample we must consider a graph that has paths between all pairs of nodes, otherwise the sum will always be positive because we will be adding an infinite quantity.

Consider a path with negative cost from a node `x` to a node `y`. Then the cost of the path from `y` to `x` must be positive and such that `D(x, y) + D(y, x)` is not negative, otherwise we'd have a negative cycle, which isn't allowed.

Since each negative cost path must have a positive cost (return path + initial path), the statement is true for this case.

Comment: `D(3,1) = infinity`, and thus sum of all D(i,j) is not negative. (but it is infinity, which is very much a positive number)

Comment: 1) with supposing if there is no path = infinity or 0 ? how we can prove ?